# folder public access with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permissions, http-status-code-403

I am really not an expert of `.htaccess` I have a remote access to an apache server who hosts an already running `php` website. I want to create a `data` folder and grant it with public access. Now I get a 403 error when I run `http://thewebsite.com/data`. I checked the permissions which are OK and I infer this error must be related to the `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Is there a way to get around this 403 error with some `.htacess` rule ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `<directory>` directive like:

```
<Directory "path/to/data">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```